# How can I measure the total hashing power of the Bitcoin network?

Tags: network, hash, hashpower

Is there a way to measure what is the total hashing power of the Bitcoin network at a given time? For pooled mining it isn't a problem - one can rely on statistics provided by the pool (assuming one can trust them), but what about people solo-mining?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Network hashrate calculated using formula: H ~= h / t , where t is time that took to find X number of blocks and h is approximate number of hashes it should have taken to solve X number of blocks, h = X * (D * 2**256 / (0xffff * 2**208)) [Wiki:Difficulty](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aTp8oq8NIAhkJ%3ahttps://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1)

Bitcoin network hashrate stats available at [bitcoinwatch.com](http://bitcoinwatch.com/) and [bitcoincharts.com](http://bitcoincharts.com/) .

Comment: This is what I figured would be the answer, too bad this method can't be used to get finer-grained results (like for example, hour-by-hour hash speed).

Comment: You can get finer-grained results, though a bit less accurate, by measuring the time between block discoveries. You can't use the block timestamps though, you have to look at the actual times the blocks were announced to the network.

Answer (score 3):

You will find the total hashrate of the network on http://bitcoinwatch.com/ ( given in Terahashs/s and in PetaFLOPs/s ) and many other ineresting bitcoin stats on the same page.

Concerning "what about people solo-mining", not sure I understand you, but if you want to know your own "solo miner" hashrate you can get it with the bitcoind command :

```
bitcoind gethashespersec
```

Comment: Well, I would like to know how they calculated the figure. I don't want to get my own hashrate, but the hashrate of all people doing solo mining.

Comment: you would like to get the hashrate for any ip address doing solo mining on the whole bitcoin network ?

Comment: I would like to get the total amount, but in order to get that I would probably need to get all individual hashrates.

Comment: @ThePiachu: To be able to get that you would have to convince every single miner to give it to you. There is no reason to think that everyone would do that so the only way to get an idea of the total hash rate is to do what Serith suggests, to calculate it based on the difficulty.

Comment: @D.H. - I believed it would be the case. Well, that can be a possible feature suggestion to the miners' programmers;).